# Unable to see 快乐 characters in HTTP Response Data tab or in Debug Sampler

Tags: character-encoding, jmeter

As you can see in the screenshots, I am setting some user defined variables using 2 byte characters.  I'm submitting the HTTP request to create this customer using UTF-8 encoding.  The customer is being created with the correct double byte character characters because I can see them in the web app and in the DB.  The problem is that I cannot see them in jmeter.  It either shows little boxes or ??? question marks instead of the characters in the response data and in the debug sampler.  The User defined variables is showing the characters correctly.  I've added this to my user.properties file but that did not help:

```
sampleresult.default.encoding=UTF-8
```

How can I see these special characters in the response so I can Assert the record was created correctly?  Any advice is appreciated.  I am using jmeter 3.1 and JSON endpoints.

[User Defined variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/du2sN.png)

[DebugSampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mS5b.png)

Answer (score 0):

Now you need to ensure that JMeter itself is using UTF-8 encoding.

1. Configure Debug Sampler to show `System Properties`

   [image: JMeter System Properties]
2. Look for `file.endoding` property

   [image: JMeter File Encoding Property]

If you see something different - override the existing property value using one of the following ways:

1. Permanent: add the next line to *system.properties* file (in JMeter's "bin" folder)

   ```
   file.encoding=UTF-8
   ```

   JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up
2. Temporary: set the "file.encoding" property via `-D` command-line argument as

   ```
   jmeter -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -n -t ....
   ```

References:

- [Java - Supported Encodings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thank you for this helpful info.  I'm still having the issue.  I turned on the System properties in the Debug sampler as you recommended.  You'll see the one encoding I knew about.  There are several more appearing that I'm unsure if I should add those to my system.properties file?  Here they are:  `Line 96: file.encoding=UTF-8`
 `Line 97: file.encoding.pkg=sun.io`
 `Line 139: sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle`
 `Line 142: sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1252`
 `Line 146: sun.stderr.encoding=cp437`
 `Line 147: sun.stdout.encoding=cp437`